# Dictionary with 2 keys and 1 value to pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

Have a question related to PANDAS in python language. Given a Dictionary with the following structure:

```
(<Key1>,<Key2>):Value
```

**how can I convert to a DataFrame such that the rownames would be Key1 and colnames Key2?**

An example obtained using defaultdict from collections module:

```
{('chr6:286000-288000', 'chr6:152152000-152154000'): 1, ('chr6:182000-184000', 'chr6:152968000-152970000'): 1}
```

Desired output would be:

```
    chr6:152152000-152154000    chr6:152968000-152970000
chr6:286000-288000  1   0
chr6:182000-184000  0   1
```

Thanks for any help you could give!

Best,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might do the trick

```
d = {('chr6:286000-288000', 'chr6:152152000-152154000'): 1, ('chr6:182000-184000', 'chr6:152968000-152970000'): 1}

df = pd.DataFrame(d.values(), index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(d.keys())).unstack(1)
```